# SQL - Update multiple values at one position

Tags: sql, sql-update, teradata

The title isn't as descriptive as I want it to be.
Here is my task at hand: I have 17 numbers and each follow this format 12345-67 (i.e. 06037-11) What I need my numbers/strings to be is 123456-78. In place 6, I am inserting a 0.

To find these numbers I used this query:

```
select number
 from schema.table
 where number like '%-%'
 and length(trim(number)) > 1
 and length(substr(number, 1, position('-' in policy_number))) < 7
 order by policy_number;
```

How can I update them all in a similar manner without doing each individually?

**edit**: I am using Teradata

Examples of records:

06037-11
24188-18
25559-18

Comment: can u just give an example of say 3 records and what database do you use

Comment: I made some edits, by records do you mean the numbers/strings I am needing changed? 06037-11, 24188-18, 25559-18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option using the `_` wildcard character which matches on any single character:

```
update yourtable 
set number = replace(number, '-', '0-')
where number like '_____-__'
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/066093/1)

This will only update records where there are 5 characters dash 2 characters.

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
update schema.table
set number = substr(number,1,5) + '0' + substr(number,6,4)
 where number like '%-%'
 and length(trim(number)) > 1
 and length(substr(number, 1, position('-' in policy_number))) < 7
```